# How to continuously call a function when button is pressed and holed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function continuously when user press button continuously or hold a button. I have tried but function call only two times, when user press and when user release the button. I have tried this:

```
zoomIn.on("mousedown", function (e) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                ImageViewer.zoomImage(30, true);
            }, 300);

        });
```

This does not work properly. I s there any way to do this?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: setInterval and clearInterval, be sure to clear the interval on mouseup

Comment: It should work in a way the function call again and again until user hold the button

Comment: Give a name to the handler function, and call that function. Then you have to assign the timeout to a variable in the outer scope. Also, you need two more events to detect when to stop, `mouseup` and `mouseleave` for example. In these handlers, use the formerly mentioned variable to reset the timer.

Comment: @Shilly how i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try some like this:

```
var interval,
    time = 100;

var zoom = function() {
    //your zooming code:
    ImageViewer.zoomImage(30, true);
};

var startZoom = function() {
    interval = setInterval( zoom, time );
};

var stopZoom = function() {
    clearInterval( interval );
};

zoomIn.on("mousedown", startZoom);
zoomIn.on("mouseup", stopZoom);
```

Comment: Thanks @legotin.Its running like a champ.